# Why does looping a session array key in PHP not work compared to explicit declaration

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am new to web development, I am trying an algorithm to loop a **session** array key in PHP instead of explicit/individual declaration and without the use of actual arrays as I noticed that **session** array key can be a variable value, here is an example of the code I am working on:

```
//this doesn't work
for($x=1;$x<4;$x++){
        echo "$x".$_REQUEST["'text".$x."'"];
}
//this works
echo "<br>1".$_REQUEST["text1"];
echo "<br>2".$_REQUEST["text2"];
echo "<br>3".$_REQUEST["text3"];
```

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: _"what could be the solution for this?"_ - to realize that `text1` and `'text1'` are different things.

Answer (score 0):

It's `echo "<br>".$x.$_REQUEST["text".$x];`

Btw `$_REQUEST` and `$_SESSION` are different beasts.